# Conduit and creating conduit based libraries

Tags: haskell, conduit

I know that Conduit is a solution to the streaming data problem for
handling data in constant memory.

I see lot of libraries in hackage with conduit name attached to it.
Some examples being [cvs-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-conduit), [zlib-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-conduit), [attoparsec-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-conduit),
etc.

So, how to make some ordinary library conduit based ? Just by using the main [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit)
package, does it qualify of giving the solution to streaming data
problem ?

I tried to dig into the source of csv-conduit and it was way
too complex. (Well way bigger (much bigger) than the complete csv
parser implemented in RWH book.) Also this [github library](https://github.com/fpco/github) actually uses Conduit, so does that also handle streaming data in constant memory ?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, I'd recommend starting with the [SoH tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, main conduit package is pretty much everything you would need to start.

The idea is that you organize your workflow in `Conduit`s. Take some elements in - push some elements out. On the basic level you can go pretty far just by using `await` and `yield`. Just use them in a monad, like this:

```
idConduit =
  do mElt <- await
     case mElt of
       Nothing -> return ()
       Just element ->
         do yield element
            idConduit
```

Then you put them between `Sink` and `Source` like `mySink $= myConduit1 $= myConduit2 $$ mySource` and you are done.

If you want to read files with them, try `attoparsec-conduit` as well.